# How to split an array for KNN?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, knn

I'm using the brute-force algorithm for KNN to find nearest neighbors in my web service.
One downside of this approach is that I need enough memory on every machine to load the whole array for KNN.
Now I'm thinking of splitting the array, do KNN separately on many machines, and then merge the results using merge sort.
But that would be slow if the client need to create a lot of connections to query each part of the result.

I have read about algorithms like `KDTree` and `Balltree` in the documentation of `sklearn`, I wonder if I can somehow separate the array so that I can quickly check which part of the array I need to look into to find nearest neighbors.

Comment: You haven't really asked a question here. Is your issue that your dataset is too large to fit into memory?

Comment: Don't you want to use spark knn to avoid problem of memory ? https://github.com/saurfang/spark-knn